# How to query mongodb to fetch results based on values nested parameters?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am working with MongoDB for the first time.

I have a collection whose each document is roughly of the following form in MongoDB:

```
{
   "name":[
      {
         "value":"abc",
         "created_on":"2020-02-06 06:11:21.340611+00:00"
      },
      {
         "value":"xyz",
         "created_on":"2020-02-07 06:11:21.340611+00:00"
      }
   ],
   "score":[
      {
         "value":12,
         "created_on":"2020-02-06 06:11:21.340611+00:00"
      },
      {
         "value":13,
         "created_on":"2020-02-07 06:11:21.340611+00:00"
      }
   ]
}
```

How will I form a query so that I get the latest updated values of each field in the given document. I went through [Query Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/), but I wasn't able to figure out how It is.

My expected output is:

```
{
    "name": "xyz",
    "score": "13"
}
```

Comment: Please show the expected output and the field with which you want max value

Comment: @deltaforce : I guess latest values be always pushed to name & score arrays ? or can the latest values act as updates to the existing record rather than adding new object to array ?

Comment: @whoami : Iatest values will always be pushed to name & score arrays as I've to maintain update history of each name & score.

Comment: @whoami: I'm still working on it. Will accept as soon as I test and validate it soon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always do push new/latest values to arrays **name** & **score**, then you can try below query, it would get last element from array as in general new/latest values will always be added as last element in an array :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $addFields: { name: { $arrayElemAt: ['$name', -1] }, score: { $arrayElemAt: ['$score', -1] } } },
    { $addFields: { name: '$name.value', score: '$score.value' } }])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kpUaFIjc8jV)